# API Gateway returns "Lambda invocation failed with status: 502" sometimes

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm having a weird problem with API Gateway and Lambda, sometimes the request fails and the API Gateway logs shows the error: "*Lambda invocation failed with status: 502. Lambda request id: f8fdb11a-99d5-44a7-9f17-04271499437f*".

I have an authorizer between the request and the lambda, and when this error happens I see only that the authorizer was called without errors, but there are no logs at all on the lambda that should be called.

This error keeps happening on the same request until the lambda container resets, I'm saying this because when it starts working again is when the remote address of the request changes.

Comment: maybe the authorizer returns a wrong result? As this result is cached it may be only created when a new lambda container runs...

Comment: @emilio I log the authorizer response, and the json is correct. Cache is disabled for this authorizer.

Comment: Further you might enable API Gateway logs to identify the response of the authorizer